# intercepting http proxy - disadvantages compared to a normal proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, network-programming, network-protocols

I would like to know how "realistic" is to consider implementing an intercepting proxy(with cache support) for the **purpose of web filtering**. I would like to support also IPv6, authentication of clients and caching.

Reading to the list of disadvantages from squid wiki http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy that implements an intercepting proxy, it mentions some things to consider as disadvantages when using it(that I want to clarify):

1. Requires IPv4 with NAT - proxy intercepting does not support IPv6, why ?
2. it causes path-MTU (PMTUD) to possibly fail - why ?
3. Proxy authentication does not work - client thinks it's talking directly to the originating server, in there a way to do authentication in this case ?
4. Interception Caching only supports the HTTP protocol, not gopher, SSL, or FTP. You cannot setup a redirection-rule to the proxy server for other protocols other than HTTP since it will not know how to deal with it - This seems quite plausible as the way redirecting of traffic to proxy is done in this case is by a firewall changing the destination address of a packet from the originating server to the proxy's own address(Destination NAT). How would in this case, if i want to intercept other protocols besides http know where the connection was intended to go so I can relay it to that destination ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Traffic may be intercepted in many ways. It does not necessarily need to use NAT (which is not supported in IPv6). A transparent interception will surely not use NAT for example (transparent in the sense that the Proxy will not generate requests with his own address but with the client address, spoofing the IP address).
2. PMTUD is used to detect the largest MTU size available in the path between the client and server and vise versa, it is useful for avoiding fragmentation of Ip packets on the path between the client and server. When you use a Proxy in the middle, even if the MTU is detected, it not necessarily the same as the one from the client to the proxy and from the proxy to the server. But this is not always relevant, it depends on what traffic is being served and how the proxy is behaving.
3. If the proxy is authenticating in the client behalf, it needs to be aware of the authentication method, and it will probably need some cookies that exist in the client. Think of it this way... If a proxy can authenticate an access to a restricted resource on your behalf, it means anyone can do it on your behalf, and the purpose of a good authentication is to protect you from such possibilities.
4. I guess this was a very old post from the Squid guys, but the technology exists to redirect anything you want to a specific server. One simple way to do it is by placing your server as a Default Gateway for the network, then all packets pass through it and you could redirect the packets you like to your application (or another server). And you are not limited to HTTP, BUT you are limited to the way the application protocol works.

Comment: Thanks for prompt replays EdwardH. Regarding point 4, what approach would you suggest in order to redirect packets to an application in order to do web(or other protocol) filtering ? I am especially thinking on a Windows approach for this. It has to be something general so that I can see all application protocol traffic.

Comment: I have experience in programming with Linux sockets, there you can redirect traffic to the application even if the destination address is not one of yours. If you are going into Windows OS domain, it will be a challenge which I cannot advice on. The only point I can add here is that there is a negotiation protocol for supporting redirection between a router or a smart switch and a regular server, it is called WCCP, with it you may be able to use an external router/switch that support it, add support in your server and use it. But it has several limitation.

Comment: @EdwaardH You redirect the traffic using sockets ? So you treat traffic coming in FORWARD chain (e.g. iptables) by forwarding it as a stream of bytes to your application ?Basically your application in this case operates at the protocol level - it sees the stream of bytes that make up the http or ftp protocol then using raw sockets ? If you know any open source or reference even for linux pls let me know.

Comment: I am planning to post a generic proxy on github in a week or two, it's a work I done for exploring the Linux networking capabilities. Here is a presentation to see the general idea: [link](http://prezi.com/y7laqbbs_isy/introduction-to-gnproxy/). Just note that it's written in C. If you are interested, I can update you when I'll post it (it will be under LGPL license).

Comment: Yes, I think is also a good idea for stack overflow community if you update the link in this post. Tnx.